# We **were thinking/thought** a lot about where the best place for celebration is - Past Simple or Past Continuous?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, sentence-choice, past-continuous

Which tense is better here?

> We **were thinking/thought** a lot about where the best place for
> celebration is. In the beginning, we decided to rent a cafe, but it's
> really expensive nowadays. Later, we talked about it with our
> relatives, and they suggested their suburban house. It's better than a
> cafe because it's cheaper and not hard to get there. I will give you
> directions.

Comment: I can't see where a decision was made. I would expect a decision to use the past tense *thought*. "We thought a lot... but then decided to..." for example.

Comment: @user3169 the decision was made after their relatives suggested their house. ;)

Comment: I would use a past perfect tense: "we had been thinking a lot about"., because the thinking happened before the decision was made.

Comment: It depends on your focus. Is the story about the time when you were thinking? Or is the story about the moment of decision, which would include the fact that you thought a lot about it first? In other words, we need more context to answer you

Comment: @anouk thank you, but the sequence of actions is pretty clear here, that's why I don't think Past Perfect Continuous is suitable here.

Comment: @gotube the story is about the process of making the decision.

Comment: We were thinking a lot about where to hold the celebration when our relatives suggested their house. Generally, the continuous is used in conjunction with something that is not continuous. We were talking when he walked into the living room.

Comment: @Lambie thank you. Is it wrong then to ask, "What were you doing at the weekend?"

Comment: Not at all. But it implies that something occurred whether stated explicitly or not. Otherwise, you would have said:  What **did you do** at the weekend. By the way, this explicit/implicit idea applies to the past perfect as well.

Comment: @Lambie thank you. Could you, please, explain what you meant? If I ask in small talk, 'So what were you doing at the weekend?', does it mean I imply that they were interrupted?

Answer (score 1):

I would say Simple Past is best for your example.
You came to a conclusion, made a decision, and it was done.

> We **thought** about it for a long time.

Comment: Peter, thank you

Comment: If you are happy with th answer, please mark it as Answered (check mark) so other people looking to answer questions will know.

Comment: I'm not sure because the thinking was continuous. During this action we first decided to rent a cafe, then we talked to relatives, then they suggested, and only then we decided. So, I am still confused.